# Problems getting Zend Form to work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have tried setting up a zend site with the following directory structure :

```
application
  -configs
  -forms
  -modules
     -admin
     -default
        -controllers
           -IndexController.php
        -forms
           -Testform.php
        -layouts
        -modules
        -views
```

Then in my IndexController.php I have the following

public function contactMeAction()
 {

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = new Form_Testform();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
```

//process stuff

```
            return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
```

}

in the file Testform.php I have

class Form_Testform extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
 ......etc

But i'm getting the following error :

Fatal error: Class 'Form_Testform' not found in /home/websites/test.local/public_html/prototype/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php on line 22

Call Stack:
    0.0004     325228   1. {main}() /home/websites/test.local/public_html/prototype/public/index.php:0
    0.1742    5351472   2. Zend_Application->run() /home/websites/test.local/public_html/prototype/public/index.php:28
    0.1742    5351472   3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /opt/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Application.php:366
    0.1745    5351708   4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /opt/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:97
    0.1872    5707240   5. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch() /opt/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954
    0.2026    6016200   6. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch() /opt/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:295
    0.2029    6020692   7. IndexController->contactMeAction() /opt/ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php:513

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Basically ZF is not finding the form where it expects it to be. I think you need to have the form in `application/forms`, not in `application/modules/default/forms` like you do.

Then have it as:

`Application_Form_Testform extends Zend_Form`

instead of

`Form_Testform extends Zend_Form`

---EDIT---

So in `application/forms` you have the file `Testform.php`
That file looks like:

```
class Application_Form_Testform extends Zend_Form { 
// form code
}
```

In your controller you have (note the naming of the action... contactmeAction, not contactMeAction):

```
public function contactmeAction {
    $form = new Application_Form_Testform();
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Then in your view `contactme.phtml`:

```
echo $this->form;
```

This should work. If it doesn't I would check spelling, capitalization in your action name and make sure things are in the correct path.

Comment: See my edit. That should fix it (note the case of the name of your action).

Comment: I'm getting Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_Testform' not found, is there a way to display on screen where it's trying to look?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of getting the following things all aligned/consistent:

1. namespacing
2. class naming conventions
3. class file location

If you wish to put your form in the folder `application/modules/default/forms`, then name the class `Default_Form_Testform`.

Comment: Putting it in that folder and renaming it didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: Are you declaring/setting a different appnamespace in either a 1. `configs/application.ini` or 2. a `Bootstrap::_initXXX()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Check names/namespaces as gaoshan88 says (must be "class Application_Form_Testform extends Zend_Form" and "$form = new Application_Form_Testform()";  )

Check that your application/configs/application.ini contains these lines:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Finally create an empty Bootstrap.php file and put it in application/modules/default/ directory.